# Segmentation Fault when adding value into dynamic array

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, dynamic-memory-allocation, null-pointer

I wanted to add values into my. array

```
typedef struct teleporter {
    int start;
    int end;
}teleporters;



int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int lenght = 2;
    teleporters *teleportPlaces;
    teleporters mytele;
    mytele.start = 0;
    mytele.end = 0;
    teleportPlaces = calloc(2, sizeof(teleporters));//malloc (sizeof(teleporters) * (lenght));
    if (teleportPlaces != NULL) {
        teleportPlaces = NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        teleportPlaces[i] = mytele;
    }

    printf("Teleport END[0] = %d",teleportPlaces[0].end);
    free(teleportPlaces);
    return 0;
}
```

but everytime i add it, it gave me an segmentation error,

how do i solve this error? it'll be great if there's an article or answer about it, thanks

Comment: calloc(2, sizeof(teleporters)*lenght);

Comment: `if (teleportPlaces != NULL) { teleportPlaces = NULL; }` - what is this?

Comment: @kofemann `2` is the length.

Comment: huh `if (teleportPlaces != NULL) {`

Comment: Please explain your understanding of all lines between calloc and printf. They really need some explanation. Alternatively please explain why you are surprised by a segfault if you access via a pointer that is guaranteed by your explicit code to be NULL.

Comment: my professor told me to always make sure that it's null, if it isnt then make it null, therefore i add that  if != null

Comment: @DanielSilalahi And it makes any sense to you? To me it does not. You need to check if it is `NULL` after `calloc`, and if it is, then you should exit with error.

Comment: @DanielSilalahi you misunderstood your teacher. Just remove `if (teleportPlaces != NULL) {
        teleportPlaces = NULL;
    }`

Comment: it's 2d array, why i put 2? because well, the length is 2

Comment: tbh no, but i am no expert in c

Comment: It's not 2d array, it's 1d array of length 2. There is nothing wrong with `calloc` call.

Comment: and, thank you. turn out the problem is the if != null, looks like we'll be having a debate next monday :)

Comment: Ok, but do you *understand* why is that the "problem"?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are literally throwing away the address to your teleportPlaces right after allocating it.

Remove the if statement in which you point teleportPlaces to NULL.

In the for loop, the address teleportPlaces[i] is supposed to be the address to the beginning of your array (teleportPlaces) and an offset (i). But when you reassign it to rather point to NULL, the actual address to the array is lost, leaving you with memory leakage (since you can't free a calloc if you don't know the address to it).

Answer (score 1):

This if statement

```
if (teleportPlaces != NULL) {
    teleportPlaces = NULL;
}
```

does not make a sense. It means that if the memory was allocated successfully you set the pointer `teleportPlaces` to the allocated memory to `NULL`, producing a memory leak.

After that you are using this null pointer in the following for loop.

Remove this if statement or for example write

```
if (teleportPlaces == NULL) return 0;
```

Or

```
if (teleportPlaces != NULL) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
        teleportPlaces[i] = mytele;
    }

    printf("Teleport END[0] = %d\n",teleportPlaces[0].end);
}

free( teleportPlaces );
```

Also you could simplify this code snippet

```
teleporters mytele;
mytele.start = 0;
mytele.end = 0;
```

the following way

```
teleporters mytele = { .start = 0, .end = 0 };
```

Also do not use magic numbers like `2`. Instead of this statement

```
teleportPlaces = calloc(2, sizeof(teleporters));
```

you should write

```
teleportPlaces = calloc( length, sizeof(teleporters));
```